# What's the difference between "treiben" and "trieben"?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between *tr**ei**ben* and *tr**ie**ben*?

According to my dictionary, they have the same meaning, so are they just the same word written in a little different way?

What about the compound words? For example:

Auftreiben=Auftrieben?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`trieben` is the 1st person plural and 3rd person plural preterite of `treiben`. So disregarding conjugation, they have the same meaning.

Comment: Nota bene: "der Trieb" is the substantive for the cause of "treiben", even though the act is "das Treiben".

Answer (score 2):

> What about the compound words?

It's the same thing with compound words (actually prefixed verbs), i.e. *auftr**ie**ben* is the preterite form.

Here's an example with *abtreiben*.

> Die Seefahrer ahnten, ein solcher Sturm würde ihr Schiff vom Kurs abtr**ei**ben.
>   Als dann tatsächlich starke Böen das Schiff vom Kurs abtr**ie**ben, waren sie darauf gefasst.